# Finding how many pages john read

Tags: algebra-precalculus

John read $10$ pages of his book in the first day of holiday. He is reading $4$ pages more than he read in every day. How many pages did John read till the end of the 8th day of holiday?

I know that this is just algebra. However, the important thing is to make the correct equations.

Let's call the amount of the pages $x$

- First day: $10x$
- till end of the 8th day: $10x+28$

Comment: Ah, so it's pages now :)  Anyway, if the first day he reads $10$ pages, and if that's $10x$, then $x=1$

Comment: @Bram28 how lol?

Comment: Where do you get $28$?

Comment: Where did the $28$ come from?

Comment: @Aweygan from $4 \times 7$ If he reads $4$ pages more in every day. For example, first day: $x+4$, second day $x+8$

Comment: Where do you get $7$?

Comment: @Aweygan Number of days

Comment: You're right about needing the correct equations, and you're off to a rough start. First of all, are you trying to get an equation for the pages he reads on day $x$, or are you trying to get an equation that says how many pages he has read from day $1$ through day $x$?

Comment: @Bram28 Trying to get both.

Comment: I think you need to look at the sequence: 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 38

Comment: How is the second day $10x+28$? Please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Please note that it is not important to solve this question, the thing is to get what question means and make the correct equations. I'm not waiting for solution, just waiting for a strategy.

Comment: @C.Maxwell OK, it's a mistake to try and do both, since they are not the same. So, either try and get a formula for the number of pages read on a particular day (and *subsequently* derive a total from that), or try to get a formula for the total pages read in $x$ days directly. OK, let's try the first strategy first: can you give a formula that expresses how many pages John reads on day $x$ (and day $x$ only!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first day, John read $10$ pa ges. The second day, John read $10+x$ pages, where $x=4$, and so on.

He did this for $8$ days, and on the last day, John read $10+7x=38$ pages, where $x=4$

Therefore, you have to find the average of $10$ and $38$, and multiply it by the number of days, which is $8$.

Hint: (open if stuck)

> What is $\dfrac{10+38}{2}\cdot 8$?

Comment: The answer seems $192$

Comment: Which you get. What is the average of $10$ and $38$?

Comment: Got it perfectly!

Comment: Look at my hint if you are stuck.

Comment: This was awesome :) Why did you find the average?

Comment: Because, what is another simple way of calculating $10+14+18+22+26+...+38$?http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/qq/database/qq.02.06/jo1.html

Comment: How did you find $38$?

Answer (score 0):

The statement of this problem is very unclear you should consider revising.

However, I am reading it as John read 10 pages on the first day and four more pages each day. It seems like you are then trying to write equations (1) for the pages read on that day and (2) for the total pages read to that point.

$(1)$ Let $f(x)=10+4(x-1)$ where $x$ is the day and $f(x)$ is the pages John read that day.

$(2)$ The easiest way of writing this equation would be to use recursive series. Let $a_1=10$ because we know from the problem statement that John read 10 pages on day 1. Now, let $a_n=a_{n-1}+f(x=n)$

Thus, if you are looking to find how many pages John read on day 8 and the total pages John read up to that point you set $n=x=8$ and solve equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ giving you $f(8)=38$ and $a_8=a_7+f(8)=192$